# How to render a component using innerHTML in React jsx

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm currently writing functionality that will toggle between two views, graph and list. two is the name of the class of the view's container.

```js
  toggleGraphView() {
    const two = document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0];
    two.innerHTML = '<span>Graph View!</span>'
  }

  toggleListView() {
    const two = document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0];
    two.innerHTML = "<ShotLog shotLog={this.state.shotLog}/>"
  }
```

The component switches to the graph view text just fine ('Graph View!') but when I try to switch back to list view, I get nothing. After firing toggleListView, in chrome tools the two container contains `<shotlog shotlog="{this.state.shotLog}/"></shotlog>`. I need it to look like `<ShotLog shotLog={this.state.shotLog}/>` in order to pass props correctly.

I'm not sure where the extra quotations are coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not create React components by putting them into strings, using JSX, your code can be shortened to the following :

```
this.state.showGraph ? <span>Graph View!</span> : <ShotLog shotLog={this.state.shotLog} />
```

Using a ternary condition, you can decide what to render depending on the value of a variable, `showGraph`

`showGraph` will be stored in your component's state, accessible via `this.state`, when you want to change the value of something in your state, you will have to call `setState`, this will cause your component to rerender everything on your screen and show you what you want

Working example :

```js
class ShotLog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hi I'm a ShotLog</div>
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { showGraph: true }
  }
  handleClick = ev => {
    this.setState({ showGraph: !this.state.showGraph })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showGraph ? 
          <span>Graph View!</span> 
          : 
          <ShotLog />}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Switch me !</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

You will find the basics of JSX on the following official documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

And you can learn more here about the state of your components : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed help with. Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert of ReactJS, but I think you should return proper content instead of trying to change it via JS:

```
  toggleView() {
      if (this.isGraphView()) {
          return <span>Graph View!</span>;
      } else {
          return <ShotLog shotLog={this.state.shotLog}/>
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with @Justinas's answer, you can try doing a conditional render instead of doing it with pure JS. You can try something like this:

```
MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {currView: 'graph'};
  }

  handleToggle() {
      if (this.state.currView === 'graph') {
          this.setState({currView: 'otherView'});
      } else {
          this.setState({currView: 'graph'});
      }
  }

  render() {
      if(this.state.currView === 'graph') {
          // render your 'graph' view
      } else {
          // render some other view
      }
   }
}
```

A change to the component's state will cause a re-render so it should completely change whatever was previously there. Just make sure you have something that can toggle or update the state :)

P.S. Sorry if I made some mistakes in the react related syntax. No IDE right now lol

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to access the dom directly using document.getElementsByClassName, you can use react way to toggle the view. You can take reference to my example below.

```
class TestComponent 
{

constructor(props) {
  super(props); 
  this.state = {
    view: 'list', 
    shotLog: someVal
  }

  handleToggle() {
     const modifiedView= this.state.view == 'graph'? 'list': 'graph'; 
     this.setState(() => {
      return {view: modifiedView}; 
     });

  }

}


render() {
     const {view, shotLog} = this.state;
     <div> 
       <button onClick={this.handleToggle}> Toggle </button> 

       {view == 'graph'} && <span> Graph View! </span> 
       {view == 'list'} && <ShotLog shotLog={shotLog} /> 


     </div>
}



}
```